# How to view sliding image and video in same page

Tags: php, html

I have two mysql tables **Image**(which contains image) and **Video**(which contains video). When I will click Image button, Image slides will be displayed and same for video.
I cam see images but how can I see video also in the same panel? May be I can use different panels for different purpose but how can I do that? I am trying bellow:

```
<?php
    ...
    //DB Connection is fine !
        $sql_stmt ="select * from mainTable where type='image'; // for image
        .......//Same for viedo

        $myControl = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql_stmt) ;        
        if (mysqli_num_rows($myControl)>0)
        {
            echo "<div id='gallery' class='cssClassForLoadPanel'>";
            echo "<div class='belt'>";
                $sql_stmt ="select * from image"; //get images from image table, same for video
                $result =  mysqli_query ($connection, $sql_stmt) ;
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
                {   echo 4MyController;
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    { 
                        $image_path= "images/".$row[image_path];
                        echo "<div class='panel'><img src='$image_path'></div>";
                    }
                }
            echo "</div>";      
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Please select Audio or Video Button";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: `WHERE type='image' OR type='video'`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to achieve. Just for my understanding:
You want to use the same HTML-Container/Wrappers. Depending on what the user chooses (video or images) the corresponding content should be loaded in this cointainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here us the pseudocode. follow the steps:

1. check which button is clocked using ajax code
2. use switch-case to check and switch from image to video (which ever is true) and vice-versa
3. load the image/video page using echo"image.php"; php code

then you are done !

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but rather a discussion / clarification of what OP is trying to do.

android_bitter, you haven't given enough information about your database/tables to be certain about how to answer your question. For example, you say:

```
"select * from mainTable where type='image'; // for image -- Same for video
```

but later you say:

```
"select * from image"; //get images from image table, same for video
```

So, what is in the mainTable and what is in the images and video tables? And what is the relationship between the images and video tables? Are they completely independent of each other, or do they correlate in some way (i.e. same project, same customer, same uploader, etc.)

If so, then you may wish to use INNER JOIN to dual-request data from both tables, related by a common id.

This excellent (and fast) SQL website tutorial may help:

http://www.sqlishard.com/Exercise

Once you clarify what you need to do, then we can help further. Really, we mostly need to know:

1. What data is in the different tables, and
2. What output is desired - some idea of what you want the user to see

Creating the different *panels* on the same page is definitely possible, even "easy". It may be as simple as just putting each data type in its own div and style formatting correctly.

Comment: If I say in easy way, forget about my given code, because I am agree to change my code.
I am describing again:  I have Three tables, status(contain flag of, if image or video need to show), image(contain image file name), video(contain video file name). Now, when I will click image button I can see images sliding, when video button will be clicked video will display one by one. How can I do that? I have seen lots of example not can't solve my problem!

Comment: its not a SQL question. please see the tags

Comment: @Tuhin Did you read the question, or just the tags? All his posted code is SQL.

Comment: @gibberish sorry its not SQL question, I asked about PHP and HTML code!

Answer (score 0):

This May Also be your solution. But I think that your code is too confuse. Try to read about suggar code tatics.

Just add this code before your image code.

```
$myControl_vd = mysqli_query ($connection,$sql_stmt_vd) ;        
if (mysqli_num_rows($myControl_vd)>0)
{
    echo "<div id='video-gallery' class='cssClassForLoadPanel'>";
    echo "<div class='belt'>";
        $sql_stmt_vd ="select * from video"; //get videos from video table, 
        $result_vd =  mysqli_query ($connection, $sql_stmt_vd) ;
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_vd)>0)
        {   echo 4MyController;
            while ($row_vd=mysqli_fetch_array($result_vd))
            { 
                $video_path= "videos/".$row_vd[video_path];
                echo "<div class='panel'><img src='$video_path'></div>";
            }
        }
    echo "</div>";      
}
```